# Return collection inside collection in node by url parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, url

I have two collections:
Students:

```
{
name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
address: {type: String, required: true},
phones: {
    name: {type: String},
    address: {type: String}
}
```

And subjects:

```
{
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    students: {studentid}
}
```

I want to create inside my API a function that by writing in the URL something like: `http:apiurl/api/subjects/subject/studentid`

it returns me the info of the student that belongs to that subject

So far I have done this:

```
router.get('/subjects/:subject/:studentid',  function (req, res) {
    Subject.find({name: req.params.name}, function (err, subject) {
        Student.find({id:req.params.studentid},function (err, student))
        if (err) res.send(500, err.message);
        console.log(student);
        res.status(200).jsonp(student);
    });
});
```

But I can't get it to work

Comment: If you have a student id at hand why don't you just query the `Student` collection with that id?

Comment: I want to make sure by looking in to the url that I am seeing a student that belongs to that Subject, otherwise I am just quering a Student but I won't know if he belongs to any specific Subject

Comment: @Lima9: As you are saying u want to look subject of student by seeing in url so, there can be possibility if i can put subject name and student id which are not interrelated to each other.so,in this case ur subject of student assumption can get failed. You can achieve this thing what u are telling by putting subject id in student schema and then find student and populate by subject id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `studentId` is exactly the same type as `_id` of `Students`.

Then you can use [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to achieve what you want. For example:

```
Subjects
  .find({
    // Conditions
  })
  .populate('students')
  .exec(function(err, subject) {
    // Some code here
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have a "name" param, your params are named "subject" and "studentid".

Try changing your router definition like this:

```
router.get('/subjects/:subjectName/:studentid',  function (req, res) {
    Subject.find({name: req.params.subjectName}, function (err, subject) {
        Student.find({id:req.params.studentid},function (err, student))
        if (err) res.send(500, err.message);
        console.log(student);
        res.status(200).jsonp(student);
    });
});
```

Comment: I doesn't really matter how you name the parameter in the url if later you are assingning it to name so It could be: `name:req.params."Anything in the url that goes after : delimited by /"`